# Cant access my UEFI. (Windows 10) (Desktop PC) (Asus Motherboard name: B150M-A). Does anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: windows-10, boot, motherboard, uefi, troubleshooting

My problem is, that i cant access the UEFI Bios. I have tried booting it up from the windows bios and hitting the F2/Del key during startup (Startup is not in fast mode), but it does not work. Can anyone explain to me why this is?

(PC is not in Legacy mode)

With best regards Kirby.

Comment: From windows, try holding shift, then press restart. This should boot you to windows recovery which has a button to access the UEFI BIOS. Another option to get here is cut the power 3 times in a row during boot.

Comment: The [manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/995665/Asus-B150m-A-D3.html?page=38) insists on using the F2 or Del keys. If the time interval for it is too short, fast-press the key repeatedly during the boot.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions tho sadly none of them work. The UEFI Bios button in recovery restarts the computer, but does not start the UEFI Bios. I have also tried spamming the F2/Del keys during startup. Spamming F2 did not lead anywhere and spamming del just took me too Windows recovery

Comment: If you're seeing Windows recovery you aren't pressing the key fast enough. It must be immediately after powering it up.

Comment: I tested your solution, but as said it does not work and I have also tried holding it in during start up. Also I have tried pressing other keys like "esc" and "F10" for example. 
                                                                                                                             
    Perhaps the screen requiring to enter my password that appears right as boot up commenses is casuing the problem. The password screen was activated from the Bios  some years ago.

Comment: Try disabling hibernation.

Comment: You have tried Advanced Startup and/or failing to boot Windows 3 times?

Comment: yes i have and it did not work

Answer (score 1):

If you've already followed the [Asus guide to access BIOS/UEFI](https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1008829/) **including their video** and have not succeeded, try the following:

1. In CMD, enter `shutdown /s /t 0` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. After the PC shuts completely, hold down <kbd>F2</kbd> and *keep it depressed*. Do not remove your finger from it.
3. Press the Power button, *while keeping <kbd>F2</kbd> depressed*. Do *not* repeatedly press it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it did not work. I tried it two times. One with "F2" and another with "Del"

Comment: @Kirby, one more suggestion:  Hold the Function key while pressing F2 - some PC's invert the use of function key options (e.g., dimming screen).

Comment: I tried it and it did not work. Thanks for the suggestion tho

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super late, but I wanted to add this in case anyone else is having the same issue and finds this page. I was having the same problem with my pc. It turned out my gpu needed a firmware update to output the display during boot over DisplayPort. I’m using an Nvidia Gtx 1080. The updater can be found here https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/nv-uefi-update-x64/

So if you are using a DisplayPort with an Nvidia graphics card and having the same issue, this might be your solution. Alternatively you could also just use an hdmi and it should work as well.